# javascript username and password

Tags: javascript, authentication

Today I started learning javscript but when I tried to create an extremely basic login feature it wouldn't work.
so I'm trying to use an array to store the usernames and another for the passwords but when I enter them it comes up with wrong username or pass help.

here is the code

```
var usernames=new Array(); 
 usernames[0]="user";       
 usernames[1]="sam";
 usernames[2]="bob";
 var passwords=new Array(); 
 passwords[0]="pass";       
 passwords[1]="pass1";
 passwords[2]="pass19";

var neworold=prompt("sign in or create account"); 


if (neworold > 8 ){
var createu=prompt("Please enter your desired username");
  var createp=prompt("Please enter your desired password");

 } else {
 var username=prompt("Please enter your username");
 var password=prompt("Please enter your password");}

if (username == usernames) {
 if (password == passwords) {
 alert("");
}
} else {
alert("wrong username or pass");
}
```

Comment: Of course, you shouldn't use a client-side language for storing private information such as passwords (anyone could view them)... barring that, you need to use a loop to check each item in the array one by one.

Comment: you can't check if an item exist in an array using `==` you can use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Please learn the language before attempting to use it.

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/RE3Db/1/

**JS:-**

```
var usernames = new Array();
usernames[0] = "user";
usernames[1] = "sam";
usernames[2] = "bob";
var passwords = new Array();
passwords[0] = "pass";
passwords[1] = "pass1";
passwords[2] = "pass19";

var neworold = prompt("sign in or create account");


if (neworold.length > 8) {
    var createu = prompt("Please enter your desired username");
    var createp = prompt("Please enter your desired password");

} else {
    var username = prompt("Please enter your username");
    var password = prompt("Please enter your password");
}

if (usernames.indexOf(username) != -1) {
    if (passwords[usernames.indexOf(username)] == password) {
        alert("");
    }
} else {
    alert("wrong username or pass");
}
```

Comment: What if `neworold` length is more than 8. You need to use `neworold.length` to satisfy the condition. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Aniket Yes. Updated in my answer.